# Is there a way of doing this with flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

My main `<div>` have a fixed height, but when I try to use `box-orient: horizontal` on it, they stay all above the first `<div>`, even with an overflow hack.

I'm stuck. This is what I need:

[image: example]

and this code:

```
<style>
.box {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 450px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: box;
  box-pack: center;
  box-align: center;
  box-orient:vertical;
}

.boxitem {
  width:150px;
  height:200px;
  background:#ccc;
}
</style>

<div class="box">
  <div id="box1" class="boxitem">flexbox item 1</div>
  <div id="box2" class="boxitem">flexbox item 2</div>
  <div id="box3" class="boxitem">flexbox item 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you contain the three columns with their own containers?

Answer (score 1):

You're using properties from the 2009 spec, which is being phased out in favor of this draft:  http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-css3-flexbox-20120918/.  You actually need `box-orient: vertical` from the 2009 spec, but that still won't help you because as far as I can tell, no one ever implemented `box-lines: multiple` to enable wrapping.  You need the ability to wrap if you only want to use one flex container element.

So, the code below will cover all of your bases for browsers that supports the Flexbox spec in its entirety:  Opera, Chrome, IE10.

http://jsfiddle.net/FwfDV/

```
.box {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 450px;
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
  -ms-flex-flow: column wrap;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  -webkit-flex-pack: justify; /* optional */
  -ms-flex-pack: justify; /* optional */
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between; /* optional */
  justify-content: space-between; /* optional */
}
@supports (display: flex) and (flex-wrap: wrap) {
  .box {
    display: flex;
  }
}

.boxitem {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
}

<div class="box">
  <div id="box1" class="boxitem">flexbox item 1</div>
  <div id="box2" class="boxitem">flexbox item 2</div>
  <div id="box3" class="boxitem">flexbox item 3</div>
  <div id="box4" class="boxitem">flexbox item 4</div>
  <div id="box5" class="boxitem">flexbox item 5</div>
  <div id="box6" class="boxitem">flexbox item 6</div>
</div>
```

However, if your "boxitem" elements are regular/fixed sizes like this, I recommend using CSS Columns instead, which has a bit wider support and can do nearly the same job.

Comment: Agreed. Using CSS columns makes more sense. It's simpler and can easily display the items in the order shown above (whether the columns are balanced or filled sequentially).